# Filtering dataset for a specific date with lubridate and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to filter my `tibble` for a specific date. If I try `>=` that date & `<=` that same date, the code results in 0 rows being returned. I have identified that it is the `<=` that returns `FALSE` for rows that I believe should be `TRUE`. Below is a working example. I am only interesting in `tidyverse` and `lubridate` related responses - please do not post answers using Base R or other packages (I know how to solve the problem in these other ways.

**Data**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1572679159, 1572703322, 1572710363, 1572722578,
                                       1572727765, 1572728767, 1572730032),
                                     class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                     tzone = "UTC", label = c(EndDate = "EndDate")),
                    ID = 1:7), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
               row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

When I try the following, it returns a `tibble` with 0 rows:

```r
d %>%
  filter(Date >= as_date("2019-11-02"),
         Date <= as_date("2019-11-02"))
```

When I try this, however, it works. ***What am I missing?*** The problem is that, I would like `Date <= as_date("2019-11-03")` to return `TRUE` for all '2019-11-03' submissions (I actually have those in my dataset), but it does not.

```r
d %>%
  filter(Date >= as_date("2019-11-02"),
         Date <= as_date("2019-11-03"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the datetime object to date class and then compare. Also use `&` to include multiple conditions to check.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

d %>%
  filter(as_date(Date) >= as_date("2019-11-02") & 
         as_date(Date) <= as_date("2019-11-02"))

#  Date                   ID
#  <dttm>              <int>
#1 2019-11-02 07:19:19     1
#2 2019-11-02 14:02:02     2
#3 2019-11-02 15:59:23     3
#4 2019-11-02 19:22:58     4
#5 2019-11-02 20:49:25     5
#6 2019-11-02 21:06:07     6
#7 2019-11-02 21:27:12     7
```

Moreover, we can also use `between`

```
d %>%
  filter(between(as_date(Date), as_date("2019-11-02"), as_date("2019-11-02")))
```

Comment: Brilliant - I knew it would be something simple like that. Thanks @Ronak

Answer (score -2):

%in% mean to determine whether a particular value is included in a vector operator. So you can use `%in%` .

```
d %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2019-11-02") %in%
           (Date <= as_date("2019-11-03")))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Date                   ID
  <dttm>              <int>
1 2019-11-02 07:19:19     1
2 2019-11-02 14:02:02     2
3 2019-11-02 15:59:23     3
4 2019-11-02 19:22:58     4
5 2019-11-02 20:49:25     5
6 2019-11-02 21:06:07     6
7 2019-11-02 21:27:12     7
```